# How to encode List of Maps to json from Sqflite?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, encode, sqflite

I want to Convert `List<Map<dynamic,dynamic>` to make key for map have double quote 
currently output for this list :

```
[{product_id: 52302, name: جمبسوت اطفالي, image: https://khsomat.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/2-54.jpg, regularprice: 34000, saleprice: 27500, permalink: https://khsomat.net/product/%d8%ac%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%b3%d9%88%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b7%d9%81%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%8a/, quantity: 1}]
```

I want to be like this:

```
[{"product_id": 52302, "name": "جمبسوت اطفالي", "image": "https://khsomat.net/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/2-54.jpg", "regularprice": 34000, "saleprice": 27500, "permalink": "https://khsomat.net/product/%d8%ac%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%b3%d9%88%d8%aa-%d8%a7%d8%b7%d9%81%d8%a7%d9%84%d9%8a/", "quantity": 1}]
```

To Pass it to line_item in this Method :

```
  void createOrder({
        required String firstname,
        required String lastname,
        required String address,
        required String city,
        required String email,
        required String phone,
        required String customerNote,
          required List itemsList,
      }) {
        emit(CreatingOrderLoadingState());
        WebServices.dio.post(
          'wc/v3/orders',
          data: {
            "currency": "EGP",
            "billing": {
              "first_name": firstname,
              "last_name": lastname,
              "address_1": address,
              "city": city,
              "country": "Egypt",
              "email": email,
              "phone": phone
            },
            "shipping": {
              "first_name": firstname,
              "last_name": lastname,
              "address_1": address,
              "city": city,
              "country": "Egypt",
            },
            "payment_method": "cod",
            "customer_note": customerNote,
            "line_items": itemsList
},
```

I think this list should be converted to json to pass it to api request, so how to convert it ?

Comment: you need `json.encode()` method - the docs say: *"Converts value to a JSON string."*

Comment: @pskink when i pass to "line_items" : json.encode(orderList) 
it returns with null and the list gets his data from local db using Sqflite